# Xtext 2.10 (AbstractFormatter2): Indentation for single or multiline comments is not always correct

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

**Problem Description:**

The default indentation for single or multiline comments does not always work properly. The following issues are being faced.

- The indentation for single line comments never worked if there wasn’t already
  at-least a space or a tab in-front of them.
- The indentation for single or multi-line comments never worked if they were part of the IHiddenRegion for which a decrease of indentation was set. The current understanding is that the formatter for the respective IHiddenRegion will increase the indentation for the comments contained in it and will then set an overall decrease of indentation for the upcoming strictly alternating IHiddenRegion(s) or IsemanticRegion(s).

**Important Note:**

Kindly direct us to an already existing eclipse Xtext ticket, if this is a known issue. Or any stackoverflow threads that explain why this is happening. And what could possible be coded wrong within the formatters based on IFormmatter2. Else please read further, would appreciate useful hints, solutions that could help us reach to a solution.

**Further Explanation:**

By "default indentation" its meant that:

- The methods `applyHiddenRegionFormatting`, `createCommentReplacer` or any other related methods to manipulate comments are not overridden.
- The terminal rules for `SL_COMMENT` and `ML_COMMENT` are left unchanged and are as under (taken from ***Terminals.xtext***):

  `terminal ML_COMMENT : '/*' -> '*/';
  terminal SL_COMMENT : '//' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;`
- There are also no other known changes made to manipulate comments in any form.

The current usage/behaviour understanding of AbstractFormatter2 w.r.t. indentation is as follows, please correct if its incorrect.

Given an EObject the following ways to set an indentation collectively for text of contained IHiddenRegion(s) and ISemanticRegion(s) are available:

1. `EObject.interior().indent[]`
2. `Interior.(ISemanticRegion_Start, ISemanticRegion_End).indent[]`, where `ISemanticRegion_Start` & `ISemanticRegion_End` were taken for the keywords '{' and '}' respectively contained within the EObject.
3. `Document.set(IHiddenRegion_Start, IHiddenRegion_End).indent[]`, where `IHiddenRegion_Start` was the next hidden region of `ISemanticRegion_Start` (as explained above) and `IHiddenRegion_End` was the previous hidden region of `ISemanticRegion_End` (as explained above).

For '2' and '3' above the current understanding is that the indentation will be increased for all the strictly alternating `IHiddenRegion(s)` and `ISemanticRegion(s)` that will be in between two `ISemanticRegions` (in case of '2') or between two `IHiddenRegions` (in case of '3', the two start and end boundary `IHiddenRegions` will be included) respectively.

The indentation of the comments showed exactly the same behaviour when using any of the above approaches. Please also advise if there is always a need to override certain methods to handle formatting of comments correctly. Or the default implementations provided for handling comments are sufficient.

As an example, the behaviour of the the formatters from our projects and the one from domain model example (`org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel`) for the indentation of comments was identical. Hence providing below an example DSL with comments from the domain model example so that its easy to relate to it.

**Example domain model DSL with comments:**

```
package p1 {
    /*
     * ml one 
     */
    // sl 11
// sl 12
    package p2 {
    }
    // sl two
    package p3 {
    }
    // sl three
    /*
     * ml two 
     */
    /*
     * ml three 
     */
    package p4 {
    }
// sl four
/*
 * ml four 
 */
/*
 * ml five 
 */
}
```

In the example above comment "sl 12" is an example of the incorrect indentation case (1). And comments "sl four" and "ml four" are examples of case (2). As explained in the very beginning. Comment "sl 11" is an example of the right indentation of a single line comment when there was at-least a space or a tab in-front of it. The indentation of multi line comments works correctly also when there is no space or tab in-front of them.

**Additional Points:**

- It was also tested if it makes a difference to use grammar access for aquiring access to the required `ISemanticRegions`, i.e. `EObject.regionFor.ruleCall()` instead of `Eobject.regionFor.keyword()`, but the results were the same.
- Also in the domain model example the formatter extends `XbaseFormatter` while the formatter in our projects extends `AbstractFormatter2`, but the results of both formatters is also identical w.r.t. comments. The resulting DSL(s) and comments contained in them are in English language.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: this looks like a bug to me. can you file a ticket at https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/

Answer (score 0):

you may try this workaround

```
class DomainmodelFormatter extends XbaseFormatter {

    override ITextReplacer createCommentReplacer(IComment comment) {
    var EObject grammarElement=comment.getGrammarElement() 
    if (grammarElement instanceof AbstractRule) {
        var String ruleName=((grammarElement as AbstractRule)).getName() 
        if (ruleName.startsWith("ML")) return new MultilineCommentReplacer(comment,Character.valueOf('*').charValue) 
        if (ruleName.startsWith("SL")) {
            if (comment.getLineRegions().get(0).getIndentation().getLength() > 0) 
                return new SinglelineDocCommentReplacer(comment,"//")  
            else 
                return new SinglelineCommentReplacer(comment,"//") {

                    override configureWhitespace(WhitespaceReplacer leading, WhitespaceReplacer trailing) {
                        // do nothing
                    }

                    override createReplacements(ITextReplacerContext context) {
                        return context
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        var String elementName=new GrammarElementTitleSwitch().showQualified().showRule().doSwitch(grammarElement) 
        throw new IllegalStateException('''No «ITextReplacer.getSimpleName()» configured for «elementName»''')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for looking at the problem.The workaround that you have provided has fixed the indentation problem for single line comments when they were not preceded by a space or a tab.

Comment: But the workaround did not work for the second indentation problem which occurs in the case of comments that are part of the IHiddenRegion for which a decrease of indentation is set e.g. for SL_COMMENT "sl four" or ML_COMMENT "ml four" in the example above.

Comment: as i said: file a bug. did not digg deeper yet

Comment: Of course it works for me. Have made the following ticket on github:

Comment: The ticket on github with id "415" has been closed with comments that it is a  feature rather than a bug. Some more details on how this feature works in the light of example "Example domain model DSL with comments:" above would help. More explicitly the answer to the question "Why is the indentation of comments before the last closing brace is one less than the other comments which are in the same opening and closing brace pair?" is what we are looking for. And how can we adjust indentation so that its the same for all comments enclosed by the same pair of opening and closing braces?

Comment: The part of placing the comments at the very beginning of the line so that they don't get indented is clear. But the indentation for the comments before the last closing brace never worked even when the comment was not in the very beginning of the line. I.e. in case they were preceded by a single space, multiple-spaces, single tab, multiple tabs or a combination of the two. The formatting resulted in one less indentation for such comments, when compared to the indentation of the comments enclosed by the same pair of opening and closing braces.

Comment: As stated earlier on "Aug 9 at 8:39" and "Aug 9 at 8:48" the provided workaround fixed problem one, which is now explained in the ticket that its actually a feature rather than a bug. I.e. the case of comments at the very beginning of the line. But the workaround did not help for the second problem i.e. in case of comments preceding the last closing brace. Have checked it once again and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Can you reopen the bug and explain the issue